# Simple Recursion Issue Back ways

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class recursionExcercise4
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    boolean statement=false;
    String ch="";
    String a="I am bubbles who is a little slugger and loves apple and yellow."
    BacktoBacks(a,ch,statement);
  }

  public static void BacktoBacks(String sentence, String ch, boolean statement)
  {
    String newLine="",word="";
    System.out.print(sentence.charAt(0));
    if(sentence.charAt(0)=='.') System.out.println();

    if(sentence.length()>1)
    {
      int num=sentence.substring(1).indexOf(" ");
      word = sentence.substring(0,num);
      System.out.println(word);
    }
    BacktoBacks(newLine,ch,statement);
  }
}
```

That is the code.

The lines inside the if statement loop were added by me so you can change that but nothing else can be changed. The if statement on top must remain there. Also, I am trying to avoid loops as it makes it too easy then. Any way to do this? I tried it but need help.

The objective is to print out the words from the string that have double letters. This should also be printed backwards. So like this:

Yellow
Apple
Slugger
Little
Bubbles

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: This smells like "homework". If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: @Bohemian there is more than one opinion about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged

Comment: "if (line.length()>1)" looks wrong. What is "line"? There's no reference anywhere to a variable "line". Are you sure you can't change that if statement?

Comment: it was supposed to be sentence. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need a function to check whether a word contains double letters,

```
public boolean hasDoubleLetters(String word){
    // test
}
```

and based on its outcome, print the word after the recursive call. And you have to pass the correct argument to the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I fist need to print each word out as I am not able to do that. Any suggestions on how?

Comment: What aren't you able to do? Testing for double letters? Just look at each pair of consecutive letters and see whether they're equal (probably ignoring case).

Comment: The recursion part isn't working. Could you please help me getting to print out each word? I know the code should go inside the if(statement.length()>1) statement. I know you are not here to do my work. I really appreciate your help. Please just help me on getting the recursion to work so it prints out each word from the string like the example out i gave above. I can manage double letters part by myself. I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you so much

Comment: You need to pass the sentence minus the first word to the recursive call. You have used the pertinent function, so you should know how to get it.

Comment: So like sentence.substring(1)?

Comment: Like, except you want to strip off more than one character.

Comment: so substring(2)? I don't understand you. Please tell a little more of what you mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5904/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-user1079641)